# How do I get around the "SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED" error?

Tags: python, ssl-certificate, fbconnect

Here's the code:

```
import fbchat
from fbchat import Client
from getpass import getpass

username="john.smith"
client=fbchat.Client(username,getpass())
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try,

client=fbchat.Client(username,getpass(), ssl_verify = False)